# Regex for milliseconds

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find date time patterns in a file like this

> `Blah blah blah 2015-08-28 08:40:34,100 blah blah blah 2015-08-28 08:40:34,124  blah blah blah ....`

I am using this pattern

```
 string pattern =
 @"(?<logDate>(\d){4}-(\d){2}-(\d){2}\s(\d){2}:(\d){2}:(\d){2})";
```

Can anybody suggest how to add `milliseconds` part to this `regex`?

Comment: Please provide more context, a piece of the text with datetime value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add optional millisec pattern in the end:

```
string pattern = @"(?<logDate>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:,\d{3}\b)?)";
```

`(?:,\d{3})?` will keep millisec part optional which is 3 digits followed by a comma.

**PS:** There is no need to use `(\d)` to make it a capturing group.

Comment: Because of the sign of `?<logDate>`,so I think the last millisec pattern should be also in `logDate` group.And I think the last `$` should be also removed, because there was no `^` in the first

Answer (score 0):

I would use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead of regex

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2015-08-28 08:40:34,100", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff", null);
```

Comment: I do not have only date time string,I need to parse a text which will have other info than date and time.

Comment: Since when showing the alternatives deserves a -1? @TRS Then give us more context so that we can post better answers...

Comment: Sorry for -1.It was impulsive.I also used your code to parse found matches though.

Comment: Where does DateTime come from?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using word boundaries rather than an end-of-line anchor to make sure we have exactly 3 digits after a comma at the end of the string:

```
(?<logDate>\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\p{Zs}\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:,\d{3}\b)?)
            ^                  ^^^^^                           ^ ^
```

See [RegexStorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3clogDate%3e%5cb%5cd%7b4%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d%5cp%7bZs%7d%5cd%7b2%7d%3a%5cd%7b2%7d%3a%5cd%7b2%7d(%3f%3a%2c%5cd%7b3%7d%5cb)%3f)&i=2015-08-28+08%3a40%3a34%2c+text+more+2015-08-28+08%3a40%3a34%2c100+more+text%0d%0aBlah+blah+blah+2015-08-28+08%3a40%3a34%2c100+blah+blah+blah+2015-08-28+08%3a40%3a34%2c124++blah+blah+blah+....)

Here, `\b` makes sure only 3 milliseconds with a preceding comma are right after the seconds. Also, I replaced `\s` with `\p{Zs}` to match only a space, not newline symbols.

The question mark at the end shows that the non-capturing group `(?:,\d{3}\b)?` is optional, so all datetime values, with and without milliseconds, will get matched.

[image]